# How to match question mark in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following regex in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/\?(.+)$ ./default.php?controller=$1&action=$2&$3
```

Im expecting, if I supply an URL like `mysite.com/controller/action/?v=2` it will be translated into `mysite.com/default.php?controller=controller&action=action&v=1`

However, it doesnt work. I tried doing

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/[?](.+)$ ./default.php?controller=$1&action=$2&$3
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/[\?](.+)$ ./default.php?controller=$1&action=$2&$3
```

None worked. Then I tried replacing the ? (question mark) by x

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/x(.+)$ ./default.php?controller=$1&action=$2&$3
```

and tried passing an URL like `mysite.com/controller/action/xv=2`

That worked just as expected. I tried testing my regex and it seems alright. What wrong am I doing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query strings aren't interpreted in the RewriteRule directly, however, you can easily append it onto the end.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ ./default.php?controller=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 3):

Query strings are not detected in the rules themselves. For reference, these need to be checked with a separate condition that checks the value of `QUERY_STRING`.

However, you actually do not need to do this in your case, as you only need to use the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag to append `v=1` query parameter to the new URI.

```bash
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ default.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Now, when requesting `/mycontroller/myaction/?v=1`, Apache will serve `default.php?controller=mycontroller&action=myaction&v=1`.

If you would like to make the last trailing slash optional, then add a question mark after it (`^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$`).

For reference, `[^/]+` means "one or more characters that is not a forward slash".